# LiLi virtualization fails

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, virtualbox, live-usb

I downloaded the current [18.04.2 Desktop ISO](http://ubuntu.osuosl.org/releases/18.04.2/ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso), [checksummed](http://ubuntu.osuosl.org/releases/18.04.2/SHA256SUMS) it, and ran [LiLi](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/features) from Windows 10 to generate a LiveUSB. In Step 4, I selected the Virtualization feature shown at the [LiLi link](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/features) (see 'No reboot required').

[image: LiLi's Step 4 dialog box]

I can boot from the LiveUSB and run Bionic AOK, but the [virtualization feature](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/help/guide/step4) fails when I go to the VirtualBox folder on the LiveUSB and launch

```
Virtualize_This_Key.exe
```

A black-on-clear dialog box appears when I launch that, asking me not to close VirtualBox.

I do have Local Admin rights on my Windows 10 Pro machines (tried on several, both RS4 and RS5).

I left a request for support on 2019-07-31 on the [LiLi website](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/help/bugtrack); echo answereth not, no response.

Virtualization was enabled in the BIOS/firmware setup; I had been running Hyper-V AK on one of these boxen before I uninstalled it in advance of this test.  All virtualization methods are now uninstalled.

Anyone use this feature? Any special tips to make it work on a supported Ubuntu? Or is this app [pining for the fjords?](https://images.app.goo.gl/6Gum6wmnQuLKrGmt7)

Comment: Did you run `Virtualize_This_Key.exe` from the CLI (command.exe)? Did it output any error messages? If running from start menu did a windows dialog box pop up with an error message?

Comment: See [this](https://www.shaileshjha.com/how-to-find-out-if-intel-vt-x-or-amd-v-virtualization-technology-is-supported-in-windows-10-windows-8-windows-vista-or-windows-7-machine/) to confirm you have virtualization enabled.

Comment: Virtualization is, indeed, enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lili hasn't been updated in 3 years. The last supported Ubuntu Release appears to be Vivid Vervet. Basically no supported Ubuntu release works on Lili. The author doesn't intend on updating it:

[image: lili vivid vervet]

It is no surprise your request for help on Lili went unanswered...

Answer (score 0):

Do you installed VirtualBox? If not, then install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and try again. If it even not works then download the [VirtualBox extensions pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and do the following:

1. Open VirtualBox.
2. Select File > Preferences or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.
3. Select Extensions.
4. Click the <kbd>+</kbd> in the Window.
5. Select the file you have downloaded.

Now try again to open the program "Virtualize_This_Key.exe". If it fails again then you have create a new VM (Virtual Machine). You may need to enable Virtualization in our BIOS. Then follow this guide "[How to Boot From a USB Drive in VirtualBox](https://www.howtogeek.com/187721/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox/)".

Comment: Virtual Box comes with it on the USB. The instructions from Lili say to use theirs, not anything on the local drive. Virtualization was enabled in the BIOS/firmware. Therefore, I don't think this is the answer.